# Where can I find Torah, Tanakh, siddur in Arabic?

Tags: tanach, prayer-book, arabic

I'm an Arabic convert and I'm looking for books like the Tanakh or a siddur or anything similar in the Arabic language.

Answer (score 4):

For Siddur you can try the Farhi Siddur which is written in Egyptian Arabic. You can find info here: https://farhi.org/Siddur/Siddur.htm

For Arabic translation of the Torah you can find some here by our teacher Sa'adiah Gaon.
https://www.biblejew.com/

Answer (score 2):

The other answer from Aaron gives some suggestions; I was also able to locate [this siddur](https://mekorjudaica.com/siddur-tefillat-shelomo-arabic-translation.html) which has an Arabic translation.

Something to note is that these siddurim are in some variation of Nusach Edot Hamizrach, which differs in some ways to Nusach Ashkenaz. Depending on your beit din/community, the text might be a little different than what you're used to.